# Express req.body is empty based on middlewear placement in callback list

Tags: node.js, express, middleware

Heads up, i'm relatively new to node, express so it might be a simple answer but i don't understand why one middle-wear works and the other doesn't.

```
//Function i'm trying to use as middle-wear 
const setRecordID = function (req, res, next) {
  console.log(req.body)
  console.log("user id: " + req.user.id.toString())
  console.log("number plate: " + req.body.numberPlate)
  console.log("dateTime: " + Date.now().toString() + "\n\n")
  return next();
}
```

Im calling it in the following function

```
app.post('/record/upload', setRecordID, upload.array('images', 12), setRecordID ,async function(req, res) {

      //this returns the number plate - works
      //console.log(req.body.numberPlate);

  
      // Steps 
      // removed code to shorten question
      // 4) redirect to home after adding new record   
      res.redirect('/home');
    });
```

As you can see there is a setRecordId function call before and a setRecordId after upload.array('images', 12). The upload.array function is multer middle-wear used to upload images. If its code is required i can post it, and the req.body has value in the multer.filename function as well.

Here's the **output** from the '/record/upload' call

[image: output]

Clearly one works and the other doesn't. I'm using express.urlencoded({extended: true}), and i tried adding body-parser too (ik i didn't need to but just incase). I also tried just directly writing the function(res,req,next) in the middle-wears place and the behavior is the same. The function before upload.array returns an empty {} req.body and after the upload.array returns { numberPlate: '12341' }.

Comment: Did you parse the body`?

Comment: it works in the 2nd function call, so yea im assuming the body is being parses. using app.use(express.urlencode({extended : true }))